# How many gs could a coilgun or railgun shell withstand?

Tags: weapons

I've been reading up on coilguns and railguns, and it got me to thinking about space combat with railguns or coilguns.

I assumed that such space combat would involve ships in somewhat circular orbits around each other.  Such ships would experience angular momentum.  To keep combat distances plausible, I assumed angular velocities of 8 km/s, which is typical of earth orbital velocities.  Assuming angular momentum of 1g, this results in an orbiting combat radius of 6400 km.  As such, I've assumed the combat distance a coilgun shell would need to traverse is 6000-12000 km.  I've further assumed a meaningful maximum time to target of 60 seconds.  That means the coilgun shell needs a dV of 200 km/s.

For this purpose, I'm ignoring the incredible energy or technology this would require.

The velocity imparted on a coilgun round is related to the length of the barrel and the acceleration it experiences.  I've assumed a coilgun barrel length of 100m; EVE Online invisages such skyscraper sized railguns.  For a 100m length at a dV of 200 kps, the acceleration experienced is 20,000,000g.

A USN railgun experiences about 50,000g.

So my question, what is the maximum gs a railgun or coilgun shell could experience without disintegrating while being launched?

Comment: Likely quite a lot. You push it alongvwith magnetic forces, so it should, *relatively to other projectiles*, be a homogeneous push from the magnets. Without atmosphere you only have those forces. Only at extremes of extremes I would imagine the magnetic forces to be warping the shell. That being said, I haven't checked the exact way the magnet fields zip through the shell.

Comment: 1) Is the projectile a solid slug or an actual shell (i.e. explosive or other filler) which would lower the peak safe acceleration and 2) Does it contain electronics or mechanical systems, which would lower the peak safe acceleration?  Both of these affect the answer; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_(acceleration)

Comment: I'm assuming a solid kinetic penetrator only, not a HE shell.

Comment: I abandoned my answer as it didn't really add enough over PcMan's, but I will note that your idea of space combat is pretty weird. Continuous thrusting in a circle like that is enormously wasteful of limited reaction mass. It also isn't an orbit (no forces holding them together, see).

Comment: That was just for numbers.  I considered it based on Eve Online, which is all about angular

Comment: Kind of as an aside but regarding "*...shell needs a dV of 200 km/s.*, that's about Mach 583, which is so insanely deep into the hypervelocity regime (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervelocity) that the concept of "kinetic penetrator"  has no meaning and the projectile shape or composition is probably almost irrelevant.  A gummy bear hitting a target at 200 km/s is just as deadly as the same mass of depleted uranium.

Comment: @nukeman240 eve is driven by its underlying requirement of putting a pretty face and particle effects on top of a spreadsheet; not by realism ;-)

Comment: @GrumpyYoungMan not at all. One approximation for projectile penetration depth at those velocities is $\sqrt{\rho_p/\rho_t}$, where $\rho_p$ is the density of the penetrator and $\rho_t$ is the density of the target. All else being equal, the depleted uranium projectile would be expected to penetrate ~3.8x the distance into the target that the gummy bear would. The Newtonian impact depth approximation is even more highly in favour of a dense projectile as it omits the square root.

Comment: @StarfishPrime Are you *sure* either of those equations are relevant at 0.6 *c*?

Answer (score 11):

Very high G are possible. But not efficient or easy.

A coilgun projectile is just a hunk of matter, there is no part of it that is more or less breakable than another part.

Correctly designed, the forces acting on the projectile act on the *whole* projectile, equally. In effect the projectile would not "feel" any acceleration, it would just be accelerated.

The limiting factor in coilgun acceleration does not arise from the acceleration forces on the projectile, but from the acceleration method used. A coilgun works by creating a hugemongous magnetic field, which pulls the projectile along, by inducing an equally hugemongous magnetic field in the projectile.
But there is such a thing as [magnetic saturation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturation_(magnetic)).

However, as magnetic saturation merely makes further increases in acceleration inefficient, not impossible, this also does not impose a real limit, merely an efficiency limit.

The last limit is that the projectile gets heated up, somewhat, by the induced electrical current flowing through it. Pretty soon it will melt, then vaporize.

So, yeah. There are no fundamental laws of physics preventing acceleration of the magnitude you want, but efficiency and material science will chicken out a long time before you achieve your desired 20 000 000g. A coilgun that *does* manage this sort of acceleration would not manage to shot a solid projectile, but rather a diffuse spray of ultrahot plasma. And if you are going to shot that stuff, rather start with a charges particle accelerator in the first place, it is much easier.

It is for this reason that Railguns and Coilguns (i.e. ballistic material projectiles) are not considered good weapons for longrange engagements such as you envisage. Not against mobile targets, in any case. For example, in The Expanse, the absolute maximum distance for projectile attacks is some 1000km, with 20-200km being the preferred distance. For longer range, you should use propelled weaponry. Missiles, basically.

P.S.
If you have a ship capable of 1g of acceleration.
And the enemy shoots an unguided chunk of metal at you, regardless of the speed, that takes 60 seconds to reach you, then you will have the ability to detect and dodge the projectile.
By applying lateral 1g acceleration, you can be 17.6 **kilometres** away from the original target point. Which I'm sure you will agree makes a longrange unguided projectile useless.
That exact same projectile, from 500km away (2.5s travel time), only allows 30.6m of dodging.
And at 50km, maximum dodge is only 30 cm, utterly useless!

Comment: Thanks for that.  I guess my question becomes what is a reasonable amount of force that a coilgun can impart to the shell?  Electricity and magnetism are not strong suits for me so I'm going to simply think of this as an F=ma problem, where F is the maximum realistic force that can be imparted.  For reference, let's assume modern known superconducting materials are used.

Comment: @nukeman240 I'd file another question for that one, rather than changing this one (or tacking extra stuff on in the comments)